# Make a single string to be a part of list

Tags: python

can you guy help me.. I try to find how to make a single string into a list.

The question is like this:

The validate_users function is used by the system to check if a list of users is valid or invalid. A valid user is one that is at least 3 characters long. For example, ['taylor', 'luisa', 'jamaal'] are all valid users. When calling it like in this example, something is not right. Can you figure out what to fix?

```
 def validate_users(users):
      for user in users:
        if is_valid(user):
          print(user + " is valid")
        else:
          print(user + " is invalid")
    
    validate_users("purplecat")
```

I tried but still do not get the right outcome,

```
purplecat is valid
```

the outcome should be like that but still get in like

```
p is invalid
u is invalid
r is invalid
p is invalid
l is invalid
e is invalid
c is invalid
a is invalid
t is invalid
```

can someone explain?

Comment: That's the thing that I want to figure it out. The clue that it given only makes a string to be a part of list.

Comment: try:     `validate_users(["purplecat"])`

Comment: the users parameter for validate_users() should be a list. Otherwise, python will iterate through each character of the string which is almost certainly not what you want. To see an illustration of this: `for user in "exampleuser": print(user)` contrast with: `for user in ["exampleuser"]: print(user)`

Answer (score 6):

You're passing 'purplecat' as a string so when the loop goes through, it considers each element of the string as one thing to iterate through. Try putting it into a one-element list:

`validate_users(['purplecat'])`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are iterating over a string here: `for user in users` but `users == "purplecat"`.

Try calling your function like that: `validate_users(["purplecat"])`

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the solution. I stack nearly 20 minutes only for this. Soo to make a string be a part of the list need to come from the calling the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you pass the string "purplecat" as an argument of the function validate_users. So, users = "purplecat"

And in the validate_users function, you used the for loop which iterates the argument users. In python, if you use for loop for the string type variable, then the for loop will iterate all characters in the string.

If you want to get an output like "purplecat is valid", then you need to use "validate_users(["purplecat"])".

In this case, you pass a list of string, so the for loop in the validate_users will iterate all strings (in this case it will iterate only once since the list only has 1 element) in the list.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, if you want to make a one-element list containing a string, you would do it using `[my_string]` where `my_string` is the string object e.g. `"purplecat"`.

There are a couple of alternatives, which would allow your function to act more gracefully if a string is passed in the `users` parameter.

One option is to accept a string as an alternative to a list, and reassign the `users` variable to a one-element list if it is not already a list:

```
def validate_users(users):
    if not isinstance(users, list):
        users = [users]
    # then carry on as before
```

And another alternative would be to fail in a more predictable way:

```
def validate_users(users):
    if not isinstance(users, list):
        raise ValueError("users must be a list")
    # then carry on as before
```

You can then write the rest of the function without having to worry about whether you have been passed something other than a list.  In the latter case, it up to the caller to ensure that it passes in a list or deals with any `ValueError`.

---

For simplicity I am not considering tuples here, although you would probably want to accept a tuple as an alternative to a list, so for example instead of

```
    if not isinstance(users, list):
```

you could have

```
    if not isinstance(users, (list, tuple)):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate_users(users):
  for user in users:
    if is_valid(user):
      print(user + " is valid")
    else:
      print(user + " is invalid")

validate_users(["purplecat"])
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_valid(user):
  if len(user) >=3 :
    return 1
  return 0

def validate_users(users):
    if is_valid(users):
      print(users + " is valid")
    else:
      print(users + " is invalid")

validate_users("purplecat")
```

Comment: SO discourages code only suggestions. Quality answers include an explanation as to how/why key parts of you suggesting solves the OP's Q. Most upvotes are gained by future visitors learning something from your solution that they can apply to their own coding issues. Consider editing to increase the value of your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate_users(users):   # takes list as parameter
  for user in users:         # iterates for users[0]: ["purplecat"]
    if is_valid(user):
      print(user + " is valid")
    else:
      print(user + " is invalid")

validate_users(["purplecat"]) # make this as a list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate_users(users):
  for user in [users]:
    if len(user) > 3:
      print(user + " is valid")
    else:
      print(user + " is invalid")

validate_users("purplecat")
```

we can use "[]" at the range on it. Hope it works
and add the length of char from user to make sure the if it's right

Answer (score -1):

```
def validate_users(users):
  for user in users:
    if len(user) > 3:
      print(user + " is valid")
    else:
      print(user + " is invalid")

validate_users(['purplecat'])
```

Here is your output:

```
purplecat is valid
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.